# How to get all the elements in two lists to return a string

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of strings. Both lists can be longer, but will always be the same length. I want to return a string.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['3', '2', '1']
```

I made a function `hug` so that `hug('a', '3')` gets me:

```
'333a333'
```

The numbers indicate how many there will be.

With the lists, I want to get:

```
'333a33322b221c1'
```

I currently have:

```
list3 = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Which gives me

```
[['a', '3'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '1']]`
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I want to take each new list I made and put them all in `hug(x, y)` but I keep getting errors.

EDIT: Thank you for all the solutions, but I'm fine with what I have right now. I already figured out the hug part. What I was trying to do now, is use hug() to get the string. I know

```
hug('a', '3') + hug('b', '2') + hug('c', '1')
```

But I don't want to have to type that all out, especially if the lists are longer.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 't']
list2 = ['3', '2', '1', '5', '4']
```

Comment: Why do you have `11c11` in `'333a33322b2211c11'` instead of `1c1`?

Comment: Typo! Sorry, I'll fix that :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start. Now you need to:

1. Create a short "hugged" strings ('333a333', '22b22' etc.)
2. Concatenate all the results.

To achieve 1, you can use Python's `*` operator. `'s' * n` concatenate the `s` string to itself `n` times:

```
def create_hugged(s: str, number: int) -> str:
    hug_side = str(number) * number
    return hug_side + s + hug_side
```

To achieve 2, use your list of lists to create a single list of hugged numbers:

```
hugged = [create_hugged(s, number) for s, number in list3]
```

Now you have list of "hugged" strings:

```
hugged == ['333a333', '22b22', '1c1']
```

So let's just join them using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
final_result = ''.join(hugged)
```

Comment: Doesn't give the output that they stated, though

Comment: That's right, but since I can't see consistency in the example output I assume there's a typo there :)

Comment: They already have `hug`. They're only asking about the second part

Comment: Mmm... my experience tells me that the lack of consistency can't be reliably attributed to a typo over some weird constraint that they didn't mention in the question. I just get grumpy when people jump on answers before the OP answered questions for clarification.... at one point this was a resource and not people making big assumptions. You wouldn't want your interpreter to just guess, why should answers about coding questions?

Answer (score 1):

Putting `[x, y]` in your comprehension is almost a no-op, since `zip` is already giving you a tuple.

Instead, you can apply `hug` to every item in the `zip`:

```
[hug(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

You can compact this using argument unpacking notation:

```
[hug(*e) for e in zip(list1, list2)]
```

The next step is to join all the resulting steps into a string:

```
''.join([hug(*e) for e in zip(list1, list2)])
```

You don't need to make an entire list to do this. Since `hug` always returns a string, you can pass a generator to `join`:

```
''.join(hug(*e) for e in zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue from what you already have:

> I made a function `hug` so that `hug('a', '3')` gets me:
>
> ```
> '333a333'
> ```

You haven't shown your code for `hug` but this would be your next step:

1. Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to get each pair of items from the two lists
2. call `hug()` with each pair, as a list comprehension or [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

   - since we don't *need* a list of the pairs, only need to iterate over them
3. use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join each item in the list/generator with the empty string `''` (nothing) between them.

```py
''.join(hug(letter, number) for letter, number in zip(list1, list2))

# output:
'333a33322b221c1'
```

Note that `list3` in your could have been created more easily as:

```py
list3 = list(zip(list1, list2))

# but since we're iterating over it just once, just keep it as a zip object:
list3 = zip(list1, list2)

# or directly use the zip expression in the for loop, as above
```